# variables declared outside of while loop not accessible inside the while loop in scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to get my head around while loops in scala.

I have the following code:

```
var basicInteger = 0
var finished = false
while(!finished) {
     basicInteger += 1
     finished = true
}
```

When I step through this code the variable basicInteger becomes inaccessible and the intellij ide tells me that it cannot find the local variable basicInteger.

Is it possible to refer to externally defined variables within a while loop in scala?

Comment: Yes it was a problem with me using the wrong operators. As you pointed out the code was all valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's something to do with the IntelliJ IDE debugger. Your code is completely valid.